# Why do I need to manually register AbpFeatureValueStore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate

I am still using 2.3.0.
I recently implemented proper permission and role management (using AbpZero).
But for some reason, `AbpFeatureValueStore` was not registered, because when getting a feature value, it always returned the default value for that feature, instead of the one written into the database. I tested this, and it seems the `AbpFeatureValueStore` was not registered to Dependency Injection.

If I manually register it in my core module with:
`IocManager.Register<IFeatureValueStore, AbpFeatureValueStore<Tenant, User>>();`
It works.

Is this not supposed to be automatically registered somehow by AbpZero? Am I missing something which will startup AbpZero properly?

Comment: Can you inject `IAbpFeatureValueStore` instead?

Comment: @aaron I don't think I actually built this from the module zero template, but I could be wrong - it was a while ago.

Comment: @aaron Yes it did work when I was using `IAbpFeatureValueStore` instead of `IFeatureValueStore`. But since `AbpFeatureValueStore` inherits both `IFeatureValueStore` and `IAbpFeatureValueStore`, I expected it to work.

Comment: Not all `ITransientDependency` classes are registered automatically. See [**Naming conventions** in Conventional Registrations](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#DocConventionalRegister).

Comment: It quite clearly says they are. `Helper Interfaces`